# I am passing a URL with area target, but everything past hashtag is missing

Tags: variables, get, hashtag

I have some links in my database that have area target in then using hashtag #.  Example:  www.mydomain.com/help/#howcanifixthis

When passing TXTurl www.mydomain.com/help/#howcanifixthis in a link and using Get in the form to input variable only www.mydomain.com/help/ shows up in the form.  The hashtag and the area name is missing.

I have tried using htmlentities($TXTurl) and urlencode($TXTurl), and still no luck.

Here is the link the php where I am trying to pass the variable with the hashtag  in it.

```
if($stmt->rowCount() > 0){
    while($row = $stmt->fetch()){
        echo "<p><a href=\"file.php?TXTlinkname=" . $row["TXTlinkname"] . "&TXTurl=" . $row["TXTurl"] . "\" target=\"_self\" rel=\"noopener\">" . $row["TXTlinkname"] . "</a></p>";
    }
```

This is how I am inserting the links with hashtags into my database.

```
$sql = "INSERT IGNORE INTO TABLENAME (TXTlinkname, TXTurl)
VALUES ('$TXTlinkname', '$TXTurl')";
```

Here is the input fields that I am passing variables to...

```
    <input type="text" name="TXTlinkname" value="' . htmlspecialchars($_GET["TXTlinkname"]) . '" id="TXTlinkname" class="form-control" placeholder="Type in Hyperlink Name Here..." autocomplete="off"> 

    <input type="url" name="TXTurl" value="' . htmlspecialchars($_GET["TXTurl"]) . '"  class="form-control"  placeholder="Enter in the URL" autocomplete="on">
```

I want to be able to pass the URL variable in a link with the hashtag to the form.  All My links in my database are to different URL's with the hashtag at the end of the link.

Answer (score 0):

Anything past the # is not sent to he server, you can use GET variables though.

Comment: Is there a way that I can use urlencode and then decode so that it uses %23 in the link and then inserts the # into the input?  I tried using urlencode in my form
value="' . urlencode($_GET["TXTurl"]) . '" 
When I attempt the above though it shows value of link https%3A%2F%2F and still cuts off after the #

Comment: Yes, what ever you want to reach the server needs to be BEFORE the #